# Cant boot after installation. Seems like not install at all

Tags: 16.04

I just bought i new computer:

```
Acer Swift SF713-51-M3B1 / 13.3" / IPS / i5-7Y54 / 8GB / 256GB SSD / Intel HD 615 / Win 10.
```

I tried installing ubuntu 16.04 with usb. I go try before installing and  everything seems normal like always. When the installation is finished the computer says i need to reboot. 
After the reboot i come to the same boot menu again. It seems like the installation didn't happened. I try reboot without the usb. It says "can't find bootable usb". 
And i choose to remove everything from the computer when installing so windows is gone. And it looks like i can't restore to factory settings either.

What can be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Go into the BIOS, enable legacy mode (sometimes called CSM), and then boot the USB installer in legacy mode. After it boots, tell the installer to erase the disk and install Ubuntu as you did before. After the install completes, remove the USB stick from the computer and then try to boot it from the internal drive

Comment: I have tried this and it says when rebooting using legacy mode: Missing operating system. No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key. The usb was in from the start but i try reconnect it without any luck. I try reboot and go F12 boot menu. I choose my usb but still goes out with the same result:  Missing operating system. No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key

Comment: What tool did yo use to create the bootable USB?

Comment: First i had my usb i created a couple of weeks ago. I used it to install ubuntu on 2 different computers with no problem.  But this failed with the new computer. Today i recreated it with a tool for linux called UNetbootin. This didnt work as well.